# How to Swift codable decode an array inside JSON without keys

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm using an API that returns this pretty horrible JSON:

```json
{
    "error":false,
    "country":"USA",
    "country_id":"881",
    "operator":"Operatp",
    "operator_id":"2053",
    "logo":"https://logo-2053-1.png",
    "destination_currency":"USD",
    "product_list":[
      "10",
      "20",
      "50",
      "100",
      "200",
      "500"
    ],
    "product_options":[
      {
         "10 RUB":"\u0026dollar;1.00 USD"
      },
      {
         "20 RUB":"\u0026dollar;2.00 USD"
      },
      {
         "50 RUB":"\u0026dollar;5.00 USD"
      },
      {
         "100 RUB":"\u0026dollar;9.99 USD"
      },
      {
         "200 RUB":"\u0026dollar;19.98 USD"
      },
      {
         "500 RUB":"\u0026dollar;49.95 USD"
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to decode the nested array using JSONDecoder, but it doesn't have a single key and I really don't know where to start. Do you have any idea?

```swift
let test = try JSONDecoder().decode(Options.self, from: data!)
for options in test.options {
    print(options)
}
struct Options : Decodable {
    let options : [String]
}
```

And the error I get

> _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription:
> "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.",
> underlyingError: nil))

Comment: There's no array, that's a `Dictionary`. Btw that's not even valid JSON, valid JSON doesn't contain `;` and `)` chars, please include the actual JSON, not the result of a console output. Also, what does your `Options` type look like?

Comment: @DávidPásztor this is an actual JSON not the result from console

Comment: No that is not json format. There are no '=' or '()' or ';' in json messages.

Comment: As said, that's the print of a `NSDictionary`. It might have been valid JSON before hand, but it has already been parsed into NSDictionary/NArray using (NS)JSONSerialization. It's using the OpenStep Format. `let dict = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]; print(dict as NSDictionary); print(dict)`, you'll see.

Comment: My guess is that you have an array of dictionaries but you should really consult the documentation for the API.

Comment: Show how did you print your "{ country = COUNTRY;", then we might help. Also, what is `data`? Could you `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`? And what is `Options`?

Comment: @Larme this is my data
Optional("{\"error\":false,\"country\":\"Tajikistan\",\"country_id\":\"881\",\"operator\":\"Beeline Tajikistan\",\"operator_id\":\"2053\",\"logo\":\"url.png\",\"destination_currency\":\"TJS\",\"product_list\":[\"10\",\"20\",\"50\",\"100\",\"200\",\"500\"],\"product_options\":[{\"10 TJS\":\"\\u0026dollar;1.00 USD\"},{\"20 TJS\":\"\\u0026dollar;2.00 USD\"},{\"50 TJS\":\"\\u0026dollar;5.00 USD\"},{\"100 TJS\":\"\\u0026dollar;9.99 USD\"},{\"200 TJS\":\"\\u0026dollar;19.98 USD\"},{\"500 TJS\":\"\\u0026dollar;49.95 USD\"}]}")

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER - The moment I wrote this answer, the Question was different.
The author might have modified it*

So your response looks like this:

```
{
    "options": [
        { 
            "A" = "A"
        },
        { 
            "B" = "B"
        },
        { 
            "C" = "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

All that JSON decoder does is try to map the response to a pre-layedout Codable/Decodable structure. And the more specific you are, the more specific the validation is. And since Swift is type safe you have to watch out for the datatypes.

So in your case your the response looks like:

1 - a dictionary with one key "options" that is an array of stuff

```
struct Options : Codable {
    let options : [Data]
}
```

2 - "option" is an array of key-Value dictionaries (or objects)

```
typealias ElementType = [String: Data]
struct Options : Codable {
    let options : [ElementType]
}
```

3 - dictionaries each have string Keys and string Values

```
typealias ElementType = [String: String]
struct Options : Codable {
    let options : [ElementType]
}
```

4- (One Step Further) if you already know the key names you are gonna get (A, B, C)
you can create an object with optional params like this.
So each object will be populated with the correct Key-Value pair leaving the rest `nil`

```
struct MyObject : Codable {
    let A : String?
    let B : String?
    let C : String?
}
struct Options : Codable {
    let options : [MyObject]
}
```

5- (Bonus) usually in for swift styling guides, variable names are kept lowercased, so if you want to map your custom variable names you can do this

```
struct MyObject : Codable {
    let customName1 : String?
    let customName2 : String?
    let C : String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case customName1 = "A" // put whatever in 'A' inside 'customName1'
        case customName2 = "B"
        
        // default
        case C
    }
}
struct Options : Codable {
    let options : [MyObject]
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: How can you use `Any` with `Codable`, did you try this code?

Comment: You are right, it should be Data. My mistake. I will fix it.

Comment: Given the updated question it would be better to use a custom type instead of Data

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's not working lol

Comment: @Andrew Just create a custom type (struct) that matches what is inside product_options

Comment: @Andrew  Please read my answer again so you understand how it all works together.
 It explains how to handle the decoding if you don't know the response format.

But, if you do then you need to create an EXACT RESPONSE MATCH to decode it properly without any errors.
If you have unknowns and different responses, either don’t mention them in the struct or use them as Data to tell  the decoder  not to parse them.

I believe my answer explains everything clearly.